# addClass is not adding class to tr

Tags: jquery

I am using the following AJAX request...

```
    $('.act').live('click', function(){     

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async : false,
        url: req_url,
        data : {
            id : account_id
        },
        success : function(data) {
            if(data == 'banned'){
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass('danger');
                alert('updated');
            }
            else{
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
        }); 

});
```

But it's not adding the danger class to tr on success, please help me to resolve, thanks.

Comment: How can you identify a `$(this)` without using a selector? Besides, `<tr>` are notorious for being stubborn - next time try `.closest('tr').find('td')`.

Comment: @DevlshOne `$('.act').live('click', function(){`

Comment: @seoppc Wouldn't the $.ajax call need to be **INSIDE** the function() call for the delegated `click` event?

Comment: can you please give me an example, thanks

Comment: Also, `live` has been deprecated for ages. Use `on`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this)` in that context refers to the `jqxhr` object, you need to reference your element some other way.

//edit

[.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated now and shouldn't be used in new code.

```
$(document).on('click', '.act', function(){ 
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async : false,
        url: req_url,
        data : {
            id : account_id
        },
        success : function(data) {
            if(data == 'banned'){
                self.closest('tr').addClass('danger');
                alert('updated');
            } else{
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but return false; is not working on `$(document).on('click', 'act', function(){`

Comment: it should be `.act` not `act`, it was my mistake, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the context of the callbacks will be an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call.

If you want to have a different context you could do something like:

```
$('.act').live('click', function(){     
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async : false,
        url: req_url,
        context: this,  // <=== Pass context here
        data : {
            id : account_id
        },
        success : function(data) {
            if(data == 'banned'){
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass('danger');
                alert('updated');
            }
            else{
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
});
```

For more information see: [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> Type: PlainObject
>
> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to $.ajax). For example, specifying a DOM element as the context will make that the context for the complete callback of a request, like so:

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the callback function does not refer the same object as it was referring outside during the ajax call was made.

The solution here is to use a closure variable which will hold the correct reference and use it inside the callback method.

```
$('.act').live('click', function () {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: req_url,
        data: {
            id: account_id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'banned') {
                self.closest('tr').addClass('danger');
                alert('updated');
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(body).on('click', '.act', function() {  
    var myRow = $(this).closest('tr').find('td'); // you have to identify the row up here!   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async : false,
        url: req_url,
        data : {
            id : account_id
        },
        success : function(data) {
            if(data == 'banned'){
                myRow.addClass('danger'); // but you can still use it here
                alert('updated');
            }
            else
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: hello, why are we using this - `var myRow = $(this).closest('tr');`

Comment: Because it needs to be identified within the scope of the delegated click but OUTSIDE of the AJAX routine. This way, the context stays correct throughout the script.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(this)` you are  referencing is the `success` instance. Look at the code below.

$('.act').live('click', function() {
     var $this = $(this);

Then inside your success callback, use this

```
$this.closest('tr').addClass('danger');
```

**NOTE:** The use of `.live()` is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead.

[Here is how to use .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)